# Firefox not login to facebook with hybridauth

Tags: facebook, firefox, hybridauth

i use the [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/), social sign on php library for social login to my site.
Everything works fine for login to facebook, twitter, hotmail with all browsers
safari, chrome, ie, except for login to facebook with firefox.
The message i get is "Oophs. Error!", and if i press again the login button i can login normally.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Disable any firefx extension and try again.

Comment: i have all ready done this and i tried in safe mode and from different pcs, but it looks same

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Iceweasel in Debian 7.6 and I have the same result. When I change to Firefox 31.0 with firebug it is working correctly.

Try with another workstation with another operating system for check if it is failing in general or is specific for a SO and version of firefox.